# Como chamar no main o Named Query? JPA

Tags: java, query, hibernate, jpa

Galera, por gentileza, alguém poderia me mostrar como faço a chamada na classe main do @NamedQuery de uma outra classe. Segue o exemplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="edificio")
@NamedQuery(name="consultaEdificioPorChavePrimaria",query="select e from Edificio e where e.id = :id")

public class Edificio implements Serializable {

//codigo

}
```

Agradeço de verdade. Abraço a todos!

Comment: Tente fornecer mais detalhes do seu problema e se possível um exemplo [**Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do que está tentando realizar.

Comment: Amigo, tudo bem?  Estou aprendendo JPA em um livro, e fiz um exemplo pessoal de cadastro de edifícios e ele comenta varias formas de puxar uma lista do banco de dados e uma é essa do exemplo. Colocar annotation na classe que deseja listar, imprimir dados do banco. A annotation é @NamedQuery. Gostaria de saber como faço que na classe main,view, eu chame dessa classe Edificio a annotation que indica para imprimir as informações a ser compilada.

Comment: Gabriel para usar o @NamedQuery você precisa estar com todo o JPA já configurado. Se esse for o caso você pode fazer a chamada seguinte forma: 
```em.createNamedQuery("Edificio.consultaEdificioPorChavePrimaria").setParameter("id", "foo").getResultList();```

Comment: @MarlonBahniuk, publique seu comentário como resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Para usar o **@NamedQuery** você precisa estar com todo o *JPA* já configurado.

Se esse for o caso você pode fazer a chamada seguinte forma:

```java
List results = em.createNamedQuery("Edificio.consultaEdificioPorChavePrimaria")
.setParameter("id", 1)
.getResultList();
```